# Perl DBI SQL Server not returning full column

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, dbi

I am having an issue with SQL server and perl. If I run my sql statement via isql I get back what I am expecting. But when running from perl all columns after the first seem to be truncated.  I have the below set.

```
$dbh->{LongTruncOk} = 1;
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 1000 * 1024;
```

Expected output:

```
| xxxxx | 2013-08-19 10:04:53.843 | nnnn | description
```

what I am getting:

```
| xxxxx | 2013-08-19 10:0 | n | desci
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the smallest possible code that reproduces, as well as the column types in question.  Your DBD and server version may be relevant as well.

Comment: "desci" is not a truncated "description"